# Simple table view in iOS8 with swift and storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to get used to swift language so as usual after learning some basics about it I have started with storyboard and table view.I have dragged table view controller to storyboard
and created class for it and attached to view controller also.
As soon as I uncomment cellForRowAtIndexPath method I get following swift compiler error

> Overriding method with selector 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' has incompatible type '(UITableView!, NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!'

I also have included `numberOfSectionInTableView` and `numberOfRowInSection` delegate methods.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

so can anybody please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your function with this :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

}
```

This will solve your problem.

**EDIT:**

If you want to use existing function then you can remove all `!` from function and your error will gone.

Comment: hey thanks.it worked but could you please explain why we have to remove !.

Comment: Glad to help you and you can check this question for more detail..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078503/why-does-swift-uitableviewcontroller-template-use-optionals-arguments-in-tablevi