# Two UITableView, one master view and one details view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I need some help on displaying data from `Master view` to `Details view`. When a `cell` is selected on `Master view`, data will display on `details view`. [Master Details View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CwWm.png)

All other class is a `xib` file to be loaded on the `Details view` which is being `outlet` in the container view. The `implementation` is to avoid using `UISplitViewController.` I'm using `objective-c`. Please can anyone help me.

**MainContainerViewController.m**

```
+ (MainContainerViewController *)createModalContainer:(NSString*)paramStr{

    MainContainerViewController *aController = [[MainContainerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainContainerViewController" bundle:nil];

    aController.title = paramStr

    return aController;
}
```

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];

    [_masterTableView setDataSource:_masterViewController];
    [_masterTableView setDelegate:_masterViewController];

    _masterViewController.view = _masterViewController.tableView;
}
```

**MasterViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            DetailsProfileViewController *detailsController = [[DetailsProfileViewController alloc] init];
            detailsController.title = @"Details";

            MainContainerViewController *container = MainContainerViewController.sharedInstance;

            [container.detailsTableView setDataSource:detailsController];
            [container.detailsTableView setDelegate:detailsController];

            detailsController.view = detailsController.tableView;

            [container.detailsTableView reloadData];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should implement a protocol to handle this.

Comment: Please edit your post to show whatever code you have so far, and explain the exact problems you are having.  Also, can you confirm whether you have two tables in the container view controller, or two table view controllers (each with their own table) embedded in the container VC?  Why are you trying to avoid `UISplitViewController`?

Comment: because the source code is already exist and the client don't want to break the existing structure.

Comment: Use prepareForSegue method to pass data from one view to other...check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29360924/3535399

Comment: @bethinker Thanks for posting the code.  What problems are you having?  I think your `detailsController` is probably being deallocated as soon as the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method completes, because you don't have a strong reference to it.  Try making `detailsController` a property.

Comment: I tried that also and i didn't work but it did trigger the viewDidLoad method of a class but no display on the tableview

Comment: I mean the dataSource and delegate is not triggered