# click on tableview cell not move to new controller

Tags: swift, tableview

I am new to `iOS` development. one thing i want to ask when i click on the `tableViewCell` i want to move to new `viewController` but when i clicked it is giving me noting.

Here is my code-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let row = indexPath.row
    if row == 4
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("contact") as! contactsandlists
        navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
        print("error")
    }
```

Please resolve my problem

Comment: `error` is printed?

Comment: yes error is printed but it not move to further view controller

Comment: In storyboard you need to embed your current controller with NavigationController

Comment: means this code is not taking you to another `viewController` and not giving any error too ?

Comment: yess i embeded navigation controller@nirav

Comment: yes noting is doing rather then printing error@vaibhav

Comment: @Bansal okay just see my ans and do exactly ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this presentation.

This will present you're controller but it will be without navigation bar.

```
 self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you would like to present with navigation bar.

```
 self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a navigationController? If you don't, nothing is going to happen and you print "error". Another way is to change the root view controller of the window property that you find in AppDelegate

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate

    if let window = appDelegate?.window {
        window?.rootViewController = secondViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Another approach is to use create a segue between a tableviewcell and the other view controller and use `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("segueId", sender: nil)
```

Comment: can u explain perform segue indentifier method

Comment: In order to use performSegueWithIdentifier you have to build a segue. Go in the interface builder, drag a segue between the table cell and the new view controller you want to show when a user taps the cell. Select the segue, go to the identity tab and fill the identifier tab with some text like "detailViewSegue". Go in the primary view controller and execute performSegueWithIdentifier("detailViewSegue", sender: nil). Then implement the method prepareForSegue. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040692/prepare-for-segue-in-swift . You will differentiate this way.

Answer (score 0):

Make `NavigationController` to your initial view.

- Select `secondViewController` view
- Go To Editor--> Embed In --> Navigation Controller.
- set the `identifier` of that `NavigationController` using `identity inspector` inside `storyboard` see image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.You have to embed your ViewController which contain your tableview in storyboard by this procedure

GoTo Storyboard -> Click on Your Controller -> Editor (In Top Menu ) -> Embed IN -> Navigation Controller

2. Write down this code to push your Controller

   ```
   let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("contact") as! contactsandlists
   self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
   ```