# How to pass data from one view controller to another?

Tags: swift, segue

How do I pass the data from an array of one view controller to another view controller?

`FirstViewController`:

```
var myArray = ["some data"]

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
  let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
  destinationVC.passedArray = myArray
}
```

`SecondViewController`:

```
var passedArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()
  print(passedArray)
}
```

Comment: I see a syntax issue. It should be `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {` ...from http://stackoverflow.com/a/24040979/354144

Comment: @NealEhardt Signature of `prepare(for:sender:)` is changed in Swift 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this Solution for Data Transfer.

In **FirstViewController.swift**

```
let str = "Hello It's Done"
func callsecondViewController()
    {
        let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! secondViewController
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
func temp() -> NSString 
    {
        return str as NSString
    }
```

in **SecondViewController.swift**

```
var data = [NSString]()
    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let view = ViewController()
        data = [view.temp()]
        print(data)
    }
```

and you get the output String as Hello It's Done

Comment: You can either present of use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)` , but make sure you've navigation controller in the stack.